# jQuery Progress bar label displays "false"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery's Progressbar widget and the first time it's run everything is fine but when it's used a second time the label text shows "false%".
I'd like it to start back at "0%".

How it works is:
When clicking in the ".container" box it opens a modal window (jQuery's Dialog plugin) and the progress bar runs. When it's complete you can close the modal window.
Then you click in the ".container" box a second time to re-open the dialog box with a new progress bar.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mLnaaj84/)

JS:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    modal: true,
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").remove();
        $("#dialog").removeAttr("style");
    }
});
$(".container").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    var progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
        progressLabel = $(".progress-label");
    progressbar.progressbar({
        value: false,
        change: function () {
            progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
        },
        complete: function () {
            progressLabel.text("Complete!");
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                buttons: [{
                    text: "OK",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }]
            });
        }
    });

    function progress() {
        var val = progressbar.progressbar("value") || 0;
        progressbar.progressbar("value", val + 2);
        if (val < 99) {
            setTimeout(progress, 80);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(progress, 2000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Progress">
    <p>
        <div id="progressbar">
            <div class="progress-label">0%</div>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: shat do you check by false.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the first time when it pop out, it's value is defined on your html page, which is `0%`.

The second time when you use `.progressbar` to trigger it, when the value is set to `false`, the change is triggered and the text is set by the change function.

You could add `progressLabel.text("0%");` add the end :

```
setTimeout(progress, 2000);
// Set init text
progressLabel.text("0%");
```

So now the text will be `0%` again.

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLnaaj84/1/).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was going to do an `if(progressbar.progressbar("value")===false)` statement in the `change` event but your solution is much shorter :)